# Why Am I Getting Segmentation Fault When I Am Taking String Input?

Tags: c++, g++, segmentation-fault, stdin

Well, i was trying to make a message encryption and decryption program.
So, why am i getting segmentation fault?
If anyone could please help me i will be very very grateful!
I had run only the encryption function. It produced proper results. Any clue what happened?

```
        #include <iostream>
        using namespace std;
        #define max 1000
        #include <string.h>
        #include <cstdlib>
        #include <stdlib.h>
        #include <math.h>
        #include <stdio.h>


        char * encrypt(char *s)
        {
            int x = (rand()/((RAND_MAX+1u)/5));
            char *res;
            int ascii;
            switch(x)
            {
                case 0:
                for(int i=0;i<strlen(s);i++)
                {
                    ascii = (int)s[i];
                    ascii = ascii-19;
                    res[i+2] = (char)ascii;

                }
                res[0]='a';
                res[1]='$';
                break; 
                case 1:
                for(int i=0;i<strlen(s);i++)
                {
                    ascii = (int)s[i];
                    ascii = ascii+sqrt(strlen(s));
                    res[i+2] = (char)ascii;
                }
                res[0]='x';
                res[1]='&';
                break;
                case 2:
                case 3:
                for(int i=0;i<strlen(s);i++)
                {
                    ascii = (int)s[i];
                    ascii = ascii-sqrt(strlen(s));
                    res[i+2] = (char)ascii;
                }
                res[0]='z';
                res[1]='^';
                break;
                case 4: 
                for(int i=0;i<strlen(s);i++)
                {
                    ascii = (int)s[i];
                    ascii = ascii+13;
                    res[i+2] = (char)ascii;
                }
                res[0]='a';
                res[1]='j';
                break;
            }
            return res;


        }

        char * decrypt(char *s)
        {
            int ascii;
            char *res;
            if(s[0]=='a' &&s[1]=='$')
            {
                for(int i=0;i<strlen(s);i++)
                {
                    ascii = (int)s[i+2];
                    ascii += 19;
                    res[i] = ascii;
                }   
            }
            else if(s[0]=='b' &&s[1]=='&')
            {
                for(int i=0;i<strlen(s);i++)
                {
                    ascii = (int)s[i+2];
                    ascii -= (strlen(s)*strlen(s));
                    res[i] = ascii;
                }   
            }
            else if(s[0]=='z' &&s[1]=='^')
            {
                for(int i=0;i<strlen(s);i++)
                {
                    ascii = (int)s[i+2];
                    ascii +=(strlen(s)*strlen(s));
                    res[i] = ascii;
                }   
            }
            else if(s[0]=='a' &&s[1]=='j')
            {
                for(int i=0;i<strlen(s);i++)
                {
                    ascii = (int)s[i+2];
                    ascii -= 13;
                    res[i] = ascii;
                }   
            }

            return res;

        }


        int main()
        {
            int ch;
            int i=0;
            char *s;
            char *res;
            while(1) {

            cout<<endl<<"1.Encrypt\n2.Decrypt";
            cout<<endl<<"Choice: ";

            cin>>ch;
            switch(ch)
            {
                case 1: 
                cout<<"\nEnter a message: ";
                cin>>s;

                res=encrypt(s);
                cout<<"\nEncrypted message is: "<<res<<endl;
                break;

                case 2:
                cout<<"\nEnter an Encrypted message: ";
                cin>>s;

                res=decrypt(s);
                cout<<"\nDecrypted message is: "<<res<<endl;
                break; 
                default: exit(0);
            }
        }
            return 0;
        }
```

The gdb gives me this message:

```
Starting program: /home/prasanna/encdec 

1.Encrypt
2.Decrypt
Choice: 1

Enter a message: Test Line

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xb7f41aab in std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator>><char,     std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char*) ()
   from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
```

Comment: Becasue `res` is indeterminate (i.e. it is never set to a valid memory  location).

Comment: If, for example, you changed it to `char res[256] = "";`, it would work fine.

Comment: @TheBuzzSaw in this case, no it wouldn't. The `return res;` is a dead-mans-giveaway of that.

Comment: @WhozCraig Ah, you're right. I didn't see the full scope of what was going on. Yeah, it'd have to be a heap allocation (or preferably `std::string`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The immediate reason is that `char *s;` declares an **uninitialized pointer** into which you attempt to read something - `cin>>s;`.

**The real reason** is that you're writing C code and calling it C++.

Comment: Yeah I know that! Its c, but well, i drifted from my original idea. This is just to make sure my algo is working well...
So, new operator is my solution?

Comment: @PrasannaChoudhari no. `std::string` and `std::cin` is.

Comment: While I rarely agree with the last statement, I do in this case, but not for the reasons likely intended. In this case, the *`#include`* list gives me the creeps.

Comment: Well, i did char *res = new char [max] everywhere and also for *s.
Worked well...
Encryption is perfect. Decryption needs tuning..

Comment: @PrasannaChoudhari: I'm sure it works well, except for the probable memory leaks and possible buffer overflows.

Comment: Well, i think i hit one of them! :-( 
Getting some weird outputs for some test cases.
So, what exactly do u guys suggest? 
Well, this is not exactly my forte.

Comment: @PrasannaChoudhari don't take this the wrong way - I suggest starting simple, using a book.

Comment: Ok man! btw, i know it might sound ironic, but im a pretty good coder...its just that i goof up a lot!

Comment: Yes, a book from the [C++ Definitive Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/10077).

Answer (score 3):

You have not allocated memory to

```
char *res;
```

but you

```
res[i+2] = (char)ascii;
```

write to that memory. That is undefined behaviour, and most often leads to a crash.

You're doing the same in `main` to `char *s;`:

```
cin>>s;
```

Comment: Thanks!!! Got it! Well, i hate it when the solutions are silly! Even the answer to my previous question was way too silly! :-(

Answer (score 0):

You have not allocated any memory to `char* s` in main. There is no space decided to store the string you received as input. You have only declared a pointer to some area (which is not yet decided)

Use  `std::string`

or you can  use `new`

```
char *s = new char[15];
```